# Derivation of Klein-Gordon inner product

Tags: klein-gordon-equation

I've been studying the Klein-Gordon equation but I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem. The KG Equation is a second order differential equation that has solutions in the form
$$
\psi= Ae^{\pm ipx} 
$$
My problem arises when finding $A$. We need to use the inner product defined by the KG equation:

$$
(\Phi_1,\Phi_2) = i \int_{R^\infty} \Phi_1^* \stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\partial^\mu} \Phi_2 \,dx 
$$

This product has been derived from a continuity equation in the form $ \partial_\mu J^\mu = 0$, where $J^\mu = \Phi_2^*\partial^\mu\Phi_1-\Phi_1^*\partial^\mu\Phi_2$. I understand how $J^\mu$ would be conserved but it's not clear for me where does this comes from or why is it even legit to consider it a KG inner product, as it does not satisfy any properties of a norm or distance. My question is how do we find the inner product defined by a differential equation? What properties does it need to satisfy in order to be considerated an inner product?

Comment: The fact that the KG scalar product is not positive definite is exactly what prompted Dirac to try and find a relativistic form of Schrodinger's eqn which had a positive definite probability density. One could also find the KG inner product without Nöether's thm in the same way in which the non relativistic probability density is found from the Schrodinger eqn.

Comment: You do not derive $(\cdot,\cdot)$, and you do not justify it. You *define* it. The notation $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is just a convenient symbol for the integral you write. Whether this definition is useful or not depends on what you want to do with it. It turns out, there are several things you can do with it, so it is a posteriori a useful definition.